# global options for jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, settings, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery UI 1.8.10.
I want to set the UI DatePicker options in a global place for the entire site.
For example:

```
$("#qexpiration").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', isRTL: true});
```

How do I set the defaults for all the DatePickers in my site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/setDefaults

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  isRTL: true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/#redefining-widgets

you can extend any widget in UI using `$.widget`

```
$.widget("ui.datepicker", $.ui.datepicker, {
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  isRTL: true
});
```

or for datepicker specifically, you can use the `setDefaults` function

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  isRTL: true
})
```